# DispatchQueue.main.async doesn't crash but DispatchQueue.main.sync crashes?

Tags: ios, multithreading, dispatch-queue

when I am on the main thread and tries to DispatchQueue.main.async it doesn't crash the app but  DispatchQueue.main.sync does. Why so?

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: can you add the error message?

Comment: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Answer (score 5):

According to [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1452870-sync)

> sync -- Submits a block to a dispatch queue for synchronous execution. Unlike dispatch_async(*:*:), this function does not return until the block has finished. Calling this function and targeting the current queue results in deadlock

because the queue waits for itself